# Nilpotent vs Solvability

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

I know that if G is solvable, then all subgroups and factor groups of G are solvable.

I also know if N is normal in G, and N and G/N are solvable, then G is solvable.(which is kind of like the converse to the statement above)

But what about nilpotent? I know if G is nilpotent, then all subgroups and factor groups of G are nilpotent.  This can be proved by induction.

But is the converse true?  If not, what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the group $S_3{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Let me see if I follow.  Any proper subgroup is of order 2 or 3 which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ or $\mathbb{{Z}_{3}$ which is abelian.moreover cyclic.  $S_{3}$ is not nilpotent as it is centerless.

Comment: And the (proper) quotient groups are also abelian.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest counterexample I can think of is the Borel subgroup $B$ of upper triangular matrices in ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb R)$. It is solvable, but not nilpotent. Consider its unipotent radical $N$, the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with only 1 on the diagonal. It is nilpotent and normal in $B$. Then $B/N$ is isomorphic to subgroup of diagonal matrices $T$. Since $T$ is commutative, it is nilpotent. To summarize: We have an exact sequence
$$
1\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow T\longrightarrow 1
$$
with $N$ and $T$ nilpotent, where $B$ is not.

Comment: Easier that $S_3$?! :-)

Comment: Of course not :-). But much easier to think of. I have never checked whether or not $S_3$ is nilpotent or solvable (although it is quite trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe good to know : if $N \unlhd G$ and both $N$ and $G/N'$ are nilpotent, then $G$ is nilpotent (see for a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611221/prove-that-if-both-n-and-g-n-are-nilpotent-then-g-is-nilpotent)).