# question on nilpotent group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Question- If $G$ is a finite group, $N$ a normal nilpotent subgroup of $G$ such that $G/[N,N]$ is nilpotent. Prove that $G$ is nilpotent.

How i did it in my exam today- (I know my solution had to be faulty because it didn't make any use of $N$ being normal and nilpotent)

Denote $[N,N]=N'$ i.e. commutator of $N$

I tried to prove that any maximal subgroup of $G$ is normal. 
To see that, first note that $G/N'$ is nilpotent and let $K/N'$ is some maximal subgroup of $G/N'$ then $K$ is maximal in $G$ w.r.t containment of $N'$ and we know every subgroup is contained in some maximal subgroup of $G$ implies $K\subseteq P$ where $P$ is some maximal subgroup of $G$ but $N'\subseteq P$ also then, and $K$ is maximal w.r.t containment of $N'$ implies $K=P$. so every maximal subgroup of $G/N'$ gives a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Next using canonical homomorphism $\eta: G\to G/N'$ showed that any maximal subgroup of $G$ goes to a maximal subgroup of $G/N'$ and thus we now have a $1-1$ correspondence between maximal subgroups of $G$ and $G/N'$ and as  $G/N'$ is nilpotent each of its maximal subgroup is normal and thus each maximal subgroup of $G$ is also normal as there is also a 1-1 correspondence between normal subgroups of $G$ and $G/N'$.

Now tell me what did I do wrong or what did I miss. I didn't have time check my solution again in exam today. so now i was thinking on it.
what can i expect with this solution if it was a 10 marks question?

Comment: Note that the exam question is answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 1-1 correspondence between the maximal subgroups of $G$ and $G/N'$. Now see [Prove: If $N\lhd G$ and $N$ and $\frac{G}{N'}$ are nilpotent, then $G$ is nilpotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113894/prove-if-n-lhd-g-and-n-and-fracgn-are-nilpotent-then-g-is-nilpot)

Comment: Same reference as Derek Holt gave

Comment: A slightly different argument for finite groups, also using the Frattini subgroup and Frattini argument, runs as follows. For this you have to know that if a group $G$ is nilpotent, then $G' \subseteq \Phi(G)$, and if $N \unlhd G$, then $\Phi(N) \subseteq \Phi(G)$. Now let $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $PN'/N' \in Syl_p(G/N')$, so $PN' \unlhd G$, since $G/N'$ is nilpotent. But $P \in Syl_p(PN')$, so the Frattini argument yields $G=N_G(P)PN'=N_G(P)N'$. But since $N$ is nilpotent we have $N' \subseteq \Phi(N) \subseteq \Phi(G)$, and it follows that in fact $G=N_G(P)$, that is $P$ is normal in $G$.